# Problem using the principle of maximum entropy to estimate kum(alpha, beta) parameters

Tags: probability-or-statistics, estimation

I am using the method of principle of maximum entropy to estimate kum(alpha, beta) parameters, but I am not getting a reasonable estimate.

```
H[f_] = -Log[(\[Beta] Gamma[(1 + \[Beta] - \[Lambda]1 - \[Beta] \[Lambda]2)/\[Beta]]) / (Gamma[(1 - \[Lambda]1)/\[Beta]] Gamma[1 - \[Lambda]2])] + 
\[Lambda]1 Exp[Log[x]] + \[Lambda]2 Exp[Log[1 - x^\[Beta]]]

(*we take partial deriavtives of H[f] w.r.t \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Beta]*)
eq1 = D[H[f], \[Lambda]1] == 0
eq2 = D[H[f], \[Lambda]2] == 0

(*evaluating \[Lambda]1 , \[Lambda]2 , we get : *)
eq1f = eq1 /. {\[Lambda]1 -> 1-\[Beta], \[Lambda]2 -> 1-\[Alpha]}
eq2f = eq2 /. {\[Lambda]1 -> 1-\[Beta], \[Lambda]2 -> 1-\[Alpha]}

h1[n_, x_List] = Sum[Log[x[[i]] / n], {i, 1, n}]
h2[n_, x_List] = Sum[Log[1 - (x[[i]]) ^ 2] / n, {i, 1, n}]

inv2[x_] = (1 - (1 - x)^(1/2))^(1/2);
data4 = RandomVariate[
  TruncatedDistribution[{0.05, 0.8}, KumaraswamyDistribution[2, 2]], {100, 20}];
data = RandomVariate[KumaraswamyDistribution[2, 2], {100, 30}];

q = Map[h1[20, #] &, data4];
q1 = Map[h2[20, #] &, data4];
b1 = Table[e1 = eq1f /. Exp[Log[x]] -> q[[i]], {i, 1, 100}];
b2 = Table[e2 = eq2f /. Exp[Log[ - x^\[Beta]]] -> q[[i]], {i, 1, 100}];
c = Table[{b1[[i]], b2[[i]]}, {i, 1, 100}];
dd = Map[FindRoot[#, {\[Alpha], 1.9}, {\[Beta], 1.9}] &, c]
```

**I keep on getting unreasonable estimates.**

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Could you add more detail? What are the estimates you got, what do you expect?

Comment: We cannot execute your code because you have not provided all of the required definitions. The function `exp` should be `Exp` (all built-in function names start with a capital letter).

Comment: @ChrisK so i am trying to estimate the parameters of the kum distribution (alpha and beta ) using the principle of maximum entropy method ,i am expecting an estimate that is around 2 for both but i am getting alpha to be 50 and 60 ...i tried to use a truncated domain but i figured i may have something wrong in the commands

Comment: @ChrisK may i send you the actual mathematica notebook to have a look at it ?

Comment: @BobHanlon oh i see ,sorry i am new to this ...yes i am aware of the Exp syntax ...i actually dont have any problem with the actual commands ... but when i use the FindRoot command i get alphas and betas that are way outside the domain of the parameters so i figured i may have a problem with the data itself

Comment: @DanaJehad StackExchange is meant as a public resource, so please try to explain your question better here so others can benefit from the answers.  Anyhow, this isn't my area of expertise!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RQLWOM7Q1u7f2WnlI7gBUzFj-kOKPnhw

Comment: @ChrisK i see ,thank you for explaining

Comment: What you're sharing is a pdf document rather than a notebook so it's really helpful.

Comment: @JimB the code was edited ,if you may have a look at it ?

Comment: What do you consider an unreasonable estimate?  100 maximum likelihood estimates using `data4` range from 0.7 to 5.2 for the first parameter and 10^-6 to 12 for the second parameter.

Comment: @JimB i choose the true values of the parameters that i am trying to estimate to be 2 yet the average of the alphas is around 3 whichb i may get on board with but the betas estimates is way too unacceptable ...i got 0,07 so the bias would be horrible for both

Comment: I think the issue issue of appropriate but undesirable estimates is simply a fact of life. 
 Extreme estimates are because a sample size of 20 just results in lots of variability in the parameter estimators (using maximum likelihood or anything else)..  If you plot the log likelihood contours, you'll find that `FindMaximum` gets the appropriate estimates.  A more minor issue is the the estimates of the two parameters are highly positively correlated.